# How to get discord token on webclient c#

Tags: c#, discord, token, webclient

How to find your Discord Token c# token Fetcher web client ? , i couldn't do that i looked everywhere
There is such a code, but it wants captcha, I think I need a user agent, I couldn't do it, please help

Comment: You have to register with discord to get a token. This isn't something you write code to do. Open a web browser and visit discord's api site to register for a token. Then you can use that token in your code.

Comment: no this is c# email password and find token